# How do I find the L2CacheSize, L3CacheSize from C++ on Windows7?

Tags: c++, windows, cpu-cache

I am profiling my code on various CPUs running Windows7 and my results so far suggest that I need to tune a buffer size proportional to the machine's L2CacheSize or L3CacheSize. Is there a way to obtain these parameters from C++?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922249/c-cache-aware-programming might be useful

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-64-architecture-processor-topology-enumeration/ via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283171/how-to-receive-l1-l2-l3-cache-size-using-cpuid-instruction-in-x86 is what google told me.  Ick!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`GetLogicalProcessorInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683194.aspx) function to get that. It returns an array of [`SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686694.aspx) structures which contain a [`CACHE_DESCRIPTOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681979.aspx) structure, which provides the cache size information.